# How to correctly integrate tkinter.Tk.mainloop and loop over an iterator in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, iterator

I am developing a simple application to help me quickly review and sort large amount of images to two categories (review and cleanup data set for an ML task).

This time I've decided to give a try to tkinter, since I haven't had any experience with it before.

What I have now is shown below in a mix of python + pseudocode

```
import os
import shutil
import tkinter
from scandir import scandir

class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, data_root):
        self.data_root = data_root
        self.scanned = scandir(self.data_root)
        self.entry = None

        self.create_dirs(['catA', 'catB'])

        # set up main window
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.image = tkinter.Frame( .... )
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.image, ...)

        self.b_catA = tkinter.Button(self.root, text='category A')
        self.b_catA.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_catA_callback)

        self.b_catB = tkinter.Button(self.root, text='category B')
        self.b_catB.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_catB_callback)

        # other setup, packing of widgets, etc

     def display(self):
         self.load_image(self.entry.path)
         self.root.update()

     def run(self):
         self.next_file()
         self.root.mainloop()

 # I particularly don't like three methods below, 
 # especially explicit call to __next__() in next_file()

     def next_file(self):
         while True:
             self.entry = self.scanned.__next__()
             if self.entry.is_file():
                 self.display()
                 return

     def on_catA_callback(self, event):
         print("Move {src} -> {dst}".format(src=self.entry.path, dst=self.catA_path))
         shutil.move(self.entry.path, self.cat_A_path)
         self.next_file()

     def on_catB_callback(self, event):
         print("Move {src} -> {dst}".format(src=self.entry.path, dst=self.catB_path))
         shutil.move(self.entry.path, self.catB_path)
         self.next_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scn = MainWindow('/path/to/data')
    scn.run()
```

Try to describe my goal in pseudocode below

```
for entry in scandir(data_root):
    load_and_display_image_from(entry.path)
    wait_for_user_to_press_a_button()
    process_button_press()
```

I don't like that this simple loop is distributed over 3 functions: `next_file` and two button callbacks. And this spreading gets even larger, if I add more buttons.

And here is another concern: lifecycle of my application is controlled by existence of files in the `data_root`. I want main window to close when all files are processed.

Is it possible to get the loop over `scandir` iterator located in one place?

As I understand, I have to write a replacement of `Tk.mainloop()`, however, I cannot figure out, how to do it.

There is an argument in this function. I thought it is a number of iterations, but looks like is is not. When I supply some value, the window shows up and closes without waiting for button presses.

**Update**
Tried rewriting `next_file` using `yield`

```
def next_file(self):
    for self.entry in scandir(self.data_root):
        if self.entry.is_file():
            self.display()
            yield
    self.root.quit()
```

Now I don't see images, only buttons. Also tried setting breakpoints on call to `self.display()` - this breakpoint is never hit.

Comment: can't you load all names at start ? And then you don't need `for entry in scandir(data_root):` And you use variable `current_index` to get next file name to display. I think you overcomplicate it.

Comment: I can, but this does not change general idea that I don't like. Loop over iterator, returned from `scandir`, is replaced with the loop over a list.

Comment: I think you should keep what you have - changing mainloop is not good and easy idea.

Comment: BTW: instead of `next()` you could use `for` loop and `yield` instead of `return` - it should give the same result.

Comment: @furas: I've updated my question with the recent negative result.